# Exception while trying to populate ListView with contacts

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to populate contacts in `ListView` using `ListViewActivity`, Whil running the sample, I'm getting an exception. Unable to figure out the reason...

Exception is:

```
06-06 11:14:01.264: E/AndroidRuntime(24017): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-06 11:14:01.264: E/AndroidRuntime(24017): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.listviewadapter/com.example.listviewadapter.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
06-06 11:14:01.264: E/AndroidRuntime(24017):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
06-06 11:14:01.264: E/AndroidRuntime(24017):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
06-06 11:14:01.264: E/AndroidRuntime(24017):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
06-06 11:14:01.264: E/AndroidRuntime(24017):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
06-06 11:14:01.264: E/AndroidRuntime(24017):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-06 11:14:01.264: E/AndroidRuntime(24017):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-06 11:14:01.264: E/AndroidRuntime(24017):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
06-06 11:14:01.264: E/AndroidRuntime(24017):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-06 11:14:01.264: E/AndroidRuntime(24017):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-06 11:14:01.264: E/AndroidRuntime(24017):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
06-06 11:14:01.264: E/AndroidRuntime(24017):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-06 11:14:01.264: E/AndroidRuntime(24017):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-06 11:14:01.264: E/AndroidRuntime(24017): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
06-06 11:14:01.264: E/AndroidRuntime(24017):    at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
06-06 11:14:01.264: E/AndroidRuntime(24017):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:259)
06-06 11:14:01.264: E/AndroidRuntime(24017):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
06-06 11:14:01.264: E/AndroidRuntime(24017):    at com.example.listviewadapter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
06-06 11:14:01.264: E/AndroidRuntime(24017):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
06-06 11:14:01.264: E/AndroidRuntime(24017):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
06-06 11:14:01.264: E/AndroidRuntime(24017):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
06-06 11:14:01.264: E/AndroidRuntime(24017):    ... 11 more
```

My Activity class is:

package com.example.listviewadapter;

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;
static final String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {ContactsContract.Data._ID,
    ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};
static final String SELECTION = "((" + 
        ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " NOTNULL) AND (" +
        ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " != '' ))";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String[] fromcolumns = {ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME};
    int[] toViews = {R.id.textView1};

    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null,
            fromcolumns, toViews, 0);
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new CursorLoader(this, ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
            PROJECTION, SELECTION, null, null);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     mAdapter.swapCursor(null);

}
@Override 
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // Do something when a list item is clicked
    Toast.makeText(this, position , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

Layout file is::

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Included `Readcontacts` permission in manifest file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have

```
 <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
```

in your xml

> ListActivity has a default layout that consists of a single,
>   full-screen list in the center of the screen. However, if you desire,
>   you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout
>   with setContentView() in onCreate(). To do this, your own view MUST
>   contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if
>   it's in code)

Answer (score 1):

Your class is extending `ListActivity`, when you do this the `id` of `ListView` has to be `android:id="@android:id/list"`. And if you want to create an object of listview you can do `ListView lv = getListView();`. You set the adapter like this `setListAdapter(adapter)`

If class is extending `Activity` you will write `ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.listvew1)` and `lv.setAdapter(adapter)`.

Change your listview id

`android:id="@+id/list"`

to

`android:id="@android:id/list"`